# prove iterior of $\{x|f(x)\le 0\}$ is $\{x|f(x)<0\}$ for continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given a continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$

Prove interior of $A= \{x|f(x)\le 0\}$ is $\{x|f(x)<0\}$.

I can show $\{x|f(x)<0\} \subset \text{Int}(A)$,the question is how to show the set $\{x|f(x)<0\}$ is the greatest one.

Another similar question is interior of the graph $\{(x,y)|y\ge f(x)\}$ is $\{(x,y)|y>f(x)\}$.

Comment: The statement to be proved is incorrect. For example, we see that this fails for the constant function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: If $\{x|f(x)<0\}$ is non empty can we show the result holds?

Comment: No. For example, take
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0\\
-x & x > 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is there some general result that makes the interior exactly $\{x|f(x)<0\}$? What's the obstacle here?

Comment: Why do you think that there are any useful conditions such that this holds? Could you give some context as to why you're looking for a statement like this in the first place?

Comment: I see a example $A = \{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z_1|\le |z_2|\}$ but I can't figure out why the interior of the set is exactly $\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z_1|< |z_2|\}$

Comment: I suspect it would be enough to impose the condition that there are no intervals $[a,b]$ for which $f|_{[a,b]} = 0$ (or for which $f$ is constant, if you prefer).

Comment: Note that it's better to use `\mid` for set definitions, as in `\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z_1|\le |z_2|\}`, which gives $\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z_1|\le |z_2|\}$.

Comment: The key condition we need is that $\{x \mid f(x) = 0\}$ does not contain any open sets.

Comment: Thanks it's easy to see the set $\{(z_1,z_2)\mid |z_1|= |z_2|\}$ contains no open set,since then we can add a $\epsilon $ to $z_1$ but not $z_2$ which outside the set correct?

Comment: That's right. In other words, there is no $\epsilon > 0$ for which $(z_1 + \epsilon,z_2)$ is in the set $f^{-1}(\{0\})$, which means that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ contains no open set. Also, we could equivalently say that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ has an empty interior; I think this phrasing is more common